# Export/Merge two individual SSRS report in one PDF/report

Tags: .net, reporting-services, report, ssrs-2008

I have decent kind of requirement. I want to generate an SSRS report which is having first 2 page in portrait mode while subsequent page in landscape mode. Is is possible ? probably not.

So, what I did is made this report in two separate reports. One in portrait mode and another one in landscape mode. It is achieved but is there any programmatic way to merge these two reports in a one and provide it as a single downloadable pdf to users?

Answer (score 0):

Add those 2 reports in subreport container in the main reporter , not sure that your printer settings will be propagated there.You can design the reports like they look in portrait /landscape mode.Let me know if you have any issues after this solution.